# jQuery Datepicker: non-date value

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

In my project, I have a simple **datePicker**, and another option to select range-of-days and I display chart according to the selected date(s).

when the user select a date, all works well.
but when the user select range-of-days, I want to display in the datePicker-text-box "(manual selection)".

How can I display my text in the datepicker text-box ?

My code:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
  minDate: new Date(2016, 2 - 1, 11),
  maxDate: new Date(2016, 2 - 1, 19),
  defaultDate: new Date(2016, 2 - 1, 13),

  onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
              DispalyChart(dateText);
  }
 });

 $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "setDate", new Date(2016, 2 - 1, 13));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it something like appending placeholder to textbox...? please refer below code:

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker" placeholder="Start date:" />
<script>
  $(".datepicker").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(arg) {
      $(this).val($(this).attr("placeholder") + arg);
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I guess the following is enough: $(this).val("my text"); Thanks!